# Return a string from a function

Tags: c, string, return

Why am i getting wrong output

OUTPUT:
Enter ur name:
saurav
Your name is sa- (

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

char * func();
int main()
{
    printf("Your name is %s\n",func());
    return 0;
}

char* func()
{
    char L[10];
    printf("Enter ur name:\n");
    gets(L);
    return L;
}
```

Comment: You're invoking undefined behavior by returning  the address of an automatic variable `L` that is long gone by the time the address is used by the caller. There are *dozens* of duplicates of this question, [**this being one of them**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16738954/returning-an-array-from-a-c-function). And stop using [`gets()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/gets).

Comment: You're returning the address of a variable created in `func`'s scope

Comment: Pedantic point: Returning the value `L` is not the problem.  It is that `printf` dereferences that value to print the string contents it expects at that address.  Had code been `printf("Your name is %p\n",func());`  --> no problem except that a number rather than a name would appear.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot return pointer to local variables. Well, you can but it will not work as expected.

Your function should get the pointer as a parameter and write there:

```
void func(char *L)
{
    printf("Enter your name:\n");
    gets(L);
}

int main()
{
    char L[10];
    func(L);
    printf("Your name is %s\n", L);
}
```

Note that `gets()` is precisely defined this way.

Now, this code is a recipe for disaster. In fact `gets()` should never be used, because it does not, and cannot, check for buffer overflows. Do instead:

```
void func(char *buf, size_t len)
{
    printf("Enter your name:\n");
    fgets(buf, len, stdin);
}
int main()
{
    char L[10];
    func(L, sizeof(L));
    printf("Your name is %s\n", L);
}
```

Comment: @Smac89: Yes! I was just adding that to the answer. The question is not about that, but it is always good to remember. In fact is one of the few pieces of C that has been _removed_ from the latest versions of the language, because there is not a single good reason to use it.

Comment: @chux: Indeed. Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

You will get your desired output with a change of line in your code.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <conio.h>

    char *func();
    int main()
    {
       printf("Your name is %s\n",func());
       return 0;
    }

    char *func()
    {
       char L[10];
       printf("Enter ur name:\n");
       gets(L);
       printf("%s", L);            //changed line
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use string instead of char* :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream> 
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string func();
int main()
{
    cout << "Your name is\n" << func();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

string func()
{
    string L;
    printf("Enter ur name:\n");
    cin >> L;
    return L;
}
```

Comment: It is not tagged C++.

Comment: `using namespace std;` does not compile in C.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
static char L[10];
```

to keep it around, func will not be re-entrant